# Spelling corrector with supplementary custom dictionary

Tags: python, nltk, spell-checking

What is the best system for spell checking in python that enables the use of an external dictionary? I've seen packages that use an external dictionary to replace a default English dictionary for example. But I would like the external dictionary to supplement the existing spell check. For example, if I have weird abstract words (`dsdfw`, `peloe`, `punj`), I want the spell checker to be able to recognise them as English words for the purposes of spelling correction.

`This is na exapmle of a setence using pelloe`

Should become

`This is an example of a sentence using peloe`

Comment: Did you try [`enchant`](https://github.com/pyenchant/pyenchant)? With `enchant` you can add your own words for a session or even a permanent personal dictionary. It has support for a lot of languages and its interface is very easy to use.

Answer (score 3):

As I said in my comment, a nice option is [`enchant`](https://github.com/pyenchant/pyenchant).

Here is an example on how to use it to add words for a session:

```py
import enchant

en_us = enchant.Dict('en_US')

en_us_weird_words = ['your', 'weird', 'words', 'list', 'here']

for word in en_us_weird_words:

    # add word to personal dictionary
    # en_us.add(word)

    # add word just for this session
    en_us.add_to_session(word)

pt_br = enchant.Dict('pt_BR')

pt_br_weird_words = ['outras', 'palavras', 'estranhas', 'aqui']

for word in pt_br_weird_words:

    # add word to personal dictionary
    # pt_br.add(word)

    # add word just for this session
    pt_br.add_to_session(word)
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hmm, I heard that it was no longer maintained and not built fo Windows 64bit.

Comment: You can use `aspell` dictionaries on it as well. What I like in `enchant` is the very easy to use interface. And as far as I can tell it is still being maintained (the latest [commit](https://github.com/pyenchant/pyenchant/commit/c326777c04b9038d892af1fbb34f99e3898ed209) on the `pyenchant` tree was 11 days ago). I'm just not sure about Windows though.

Comment: Just checked [Enchant](https://github.com/AbiWord/enchant) (the spell checker) project as well and the latest [commit](https://github.com/AbiWord/enchant/commit/36ce0b94e8f7d648dd79fc888c862bc6adf08316) was 7 days ago. So both projects are still being maintained.